# Editar função nls ou nlsLM quanto ao cálculo dos resíduos

Tags: r

Preciso ajustar uma função não linear através das rotinas `nls`
 ou `nlsLM`, entretanto, meu dados geram resíduos heterocedásticos quando calculados com essas rotinas, o que não me permite ajustar diretamente através da soma dos quadrados dos resíduos

Já tenho a equação que torna os resíduos homocedásticos, mas não sei como fazer para que a rotina utilize essa forma para calcular os resíduos no lugar do cálculo direto de (observado-esperado)^2

Comment: Então José, você já tem alguma coisa pronta? Algum trecho do código? Poderia tbm explicar melhor o que quer dizer com `resíduos heterocedásticos` e `resíduos homocedásticos` isso me parece ter mais a ver com Regressão Linear -- Matematica.

Comment: Olá, @MarceloBonifazio! Eu estou usando diretamente a função nlsLM, apenas insiro meu conjunto de dados e mando rodar. Resíduos heterocedásticos ocorrem quando a diferença entre o observado e o esperado (resíduos) apresentam uma tendência em sua distribuição ao longo de x. As rotinas {nls} e {nlsLM} ajustam o modelo através da minimização do quadrado dos resíduos, preciso alterar essa parte do código

Comment: José, o código do `nls` é aberto e pode ser visto digitando `nls` no console do R. Caso você queira editar pode recriar a função, fazendo `nls <- código mostrado...` No entanto, isso não deve ser fácil. Existem outros jeitos de corrigir a heterocedasticidade mudando o modelo e não código, tem certeza que é isso que você precisa fazer?

Comment: @DanielFalbel, preciso alterar o código porque minha matriz de dados tem esse problema. Eu cheguei a abrir o código do nls, mas não consegui identificar a parte que calcula os resíduos pra fazer a alteração. Sabe me dizer isso?

Comment: Acho que não compensa alterar o código por custo benefício. Por que você não tenta ajustar um modelo com uma função para a variância tbm? A função `gnls` ajusta modelos com uma função para a variância passada para o argumento `weights`

Comment: Eu tentei usar o argumento `weights` e `varFunc` na função `gnls` mas não consegui fazer funcionar. Sou novo no R e as vezes travo em problemas simples. O que preciso é fazer o cálculo dos resíduos da seguinte forma: resid = (observado - esperado)/(ax^b). Os parâmetros a e b eu forneço manualmente conforme a matriz de dados utilizada.

Comment: o que é x na sua fórmula?

Comment: x é a minha variável independente presente na minha matriz de dados. Ocorre assim: estou relacionando peso conforme o comprimento de uma espécie (x = comprimento, y = peso), a variabilidade em peso aumenta conforme os indivíduos ficam maiores, portanto divido os resíduos por uma equação que descreva esse aumento na variabilidade (nesse caso específico, uma equação potência), eliminando, assim, a heterocedasticidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo que deve te ajudar:

```
# dados do modelo
DNase1 <- subset(DNase, Run == 1)

# ajuste do mdoelo
fm1DNase1 <- nls(density ~ SSlogis(log(conc), Asym, xmid, scal), DNase1)

# definicao de a e b
a <- 1
b <- 2

# cálculo do resíduo
residuo <- (DNase1$density - predict(fm1DNase1))/((a*DNase1$density)^b)
```

Na última parte do código, coloquei a variável resposta no lugar do seu `x`, mas não sei se é exatamente isso que você queria.

Comment: A ideia é essa mesmo, mas o que preciso é fazer com que a rotina `nls` ajuste o modelo utilizando essa equação para os resíduos no lugar de simplesmente (observado-esperado)^2

Comment: você poderia postar o código do modelo que você está ajustanto? acho que vai ficar mais fácil de ajudar

Comment: Claro. Esse é o código que estou usando para ajustar o modelo:
`poly.2p.fitted<-gnls(Weight ~ (a1 * Length^b1) * (1/(1 + exp(rate * (Length -scp))))+(a2 * Length^b2) * (1-(1/(1 + exp(rate * (Length-scp))))), data=dados, start=list(a1=0.1,b1=2.5,a2=0.1,b2=3,rate=10,scp=11), control=gnlsControl(maxIter=99999))`